Git issue with master and main branches
I recently upgraded my linux desktop with Ubuntu 24.04. This was a fresh install and as I was installing all the different programs I'm using, git was one of them. I have a local server where I host a few git repositories. I did some reorg of a couple of the repos on the server and when I did a clone to the new 24.04 desktop instance of this repo, I got a message saying something about master being replaced with main. I didn't really pay attention to it, but now I'm having some issues where I have two branches, master and main. Tonight I thought I'd get rid of the master branch and only use main.
I executed the following commands:
git branch main
git checkout main
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories

This throws the following error:
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master
usr@machine:~/bin$ fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I guess I could copy all the files in my bin directory to a temporary directory and blow out the remote repo and build a new (bare) repo on my server and try to avoid the master branch all together, but then I wouldn't learn what's going on here.
Here's my git config file for the bin directory:
git config --list
user.name=Some Name
user.email=some.name@domain.com
pull.ff=true
init.defaultbranch=main
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@192.168.1.100:/home/git/repos/bin
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master

git branch -a
* main
  master
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/master

Can someone give me a pointer as to how to get rid of master all together and only use main going forward.
I should say that I use git as a personal repo for different shell scripts I use. These files are all located in a bin directory in my $HOME.

This question is similar to: How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

master is a regular branch: delete it with git branch -d
git branch -d master
# if git prints a warning:
# double check your repo history
# if you still want to force deletion: use capital D
git branch -D

To remove refs/remotes branches that aren't actually present on the remote anymore:
git fetch --prune


From there you should have a clearer view of what is and what isn't present on your remote.
Here is a way to inspect the combined histories of your repo:
# combined histories of main, origin/main origin/master
git log --graph --oneline main origin/main origin/master

Use whatever commands (git rebase, git cherry-pick ...) to put the sequence of commits you want on your local main branch.
Then update your remote main branch:
git push origin --force-with-lease main:main

If your remote has a master branch, here is how to delete it:
git push origin -d master

